# Subir un ZIP con un input genera un fichero erroneo

Tags: javascript, java, html

Tengo un

```
<input name="shp_local" id="shp_local" type="file" ></input>
```

Puedo subir ficheros de cualquier tipo y el archivo temp que me genera en el servidor es correcto, pero al subir .zip me genera un fichero más grande e inconsistente.

Estoy usando tomcat 7.0

Al subir ficheros de mayor tamaño no tengo problemas, al parecer esto pasa solo al enviar ficheros comprimidos. Para comprobar la información que recibo en el servidor estoy usando el fichero .tmp que se genera automáticamente.

**Edit 1**

El input esta rodeado de un form que lanza un servlet, este es el código de tratamiento del fichero en el servlet

```
PrintWriter outwr = response.getWriter();
String fileType = null;
String fileName = "";
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List /* FileItem */items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
        if (!item.isFormField()) {
            InputStream inputStream = item.getInputStream();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer);
            // creem un arxiu temporal
            File temp = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".tmp");
            Writer out = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(
                            new FileOutputStream(
                                    temp.getAbsolutePath())));
            try {
                out.write(writer.toString());
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
            fileName = temp.getName();
        } else {
            fileType = item.getString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cuidado!! **Java != Javascript**.

Comment: Lo se, pero en la parte de servidor uso Java, no creo que sea el problema, pero forma parte de la ecuación. Gracias por el apunte

Comment: Perdona, suele haber muchas confusiones y la mayor parte de la gente usa PHP del lado del servidor. Creo que deberías de poner cómo estás gestionando tus ficheros o mirar en tu servidor si tienes algún limite a la hora de gestionar ficheros grandes.

Comment: La cosa es que puedo subir ficheros más grandes sin problema y conservan la integridad. El problema aparece por lo que he visto el problema se produce con los ficheros comprimidos (ahora edito la pregunta)

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo estás almacenando dichos ficheros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está aquí:

```
StringWriter writer 
out.write(writer.toString());
```

Estás conviertiendo un archivo binario en texto, por eso se hace más grande. `StringWriter` se utiliza para escribir texto. Necesitas manejar el flujo de datos como binario. Usa otra implementación como `FileOutputStream` con un bufer de bytes y asegúrate de que estás escribiendo `bytes` y no `Strings`. También existen ya varios frameworks que facilitan el manejo de archivos como el `commons-fileupload` que se usa en Struts2.

Intenta así:

```
byte[] bufer = new byte[8192];
FileOutputStream fos = null;

File temp = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".tmp");
fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);

int cuenta;
while ((cuenta = fis.read(bufer)) > 0) {
    fos.write(bufer, 0, cuenta);
}
```